# Unsupported string encoding using Blaze Data(engine)

Tags: python, pandas, blaze

Is there a workaround for this?

I have a MSSQL table that uses collation settings of SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'+ServerName+'/'+Database+'?driver='+ServerDriver+'?charset=cp2150')
```

I am able to load it into a pandas DataFrame with

```
prov_chunk = pd.read_sql('select * from table_name,engine')
```

But hit an error when I try to use Blaze

```
    #Error
C:\Anaconda\envs\care\lib\site-packages\datashape\coretypes.pyc in __init__(self, *args)
    361         except KeyError:
    362             raise ValueError('Unsupported string encoding %s' %
--> 363                              repr(encoding))
    364 
    365         self.encoding = encoding

ValueError: Unsupported string encoding u'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
```

I cannot change the collation and would like to use Blaze more for my own data analysis. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `ServerDriver`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer, but it might be still useful for someone.

Blaze relies on the package [`datashape`](http://datashape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) when detecting and validating database collations. However, the set of encodings recognized by `datashape` is currently extremely small. They are stored in the protected module variable `_canonical_string_encodings`. As of [version 0.5.2](https://github.com/blaze/datashape/blob/2a66ca28f10314394ee7ba0eb13433e2cb55fee1/datashape/coretypes.py#L353), only a few aliases for `ascii`, `utf-8`,`utf-16`, and `utf-32` are supported, but no encodings such as your `Latin-1`, or in my case, `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as used by MySQL.

To fix this, it is possible to add new encodings to `_canonical_string_encodings`. With the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation, try inserting the following lines before you call a `Blaze` method for the first time:

```py
import datashape
datashape.coretypes._canonical_string_encodings.update({"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS": "A"})
```

These lines of code add a key for your encoding to the dictionary, and pretends that this is a `ascii` encoding. If this doesn't work (because there are characters in your data that don't fit into `ascii` encoding), try `"U8"` instead of `"A"`. `"U8"` did the job for my `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation.

Monkey-patching `datashape` like is, however, more a hack than a real solution. The dictionary `_canonical_string_encodings` is marked as protected, but the hack ignores this. Be warned that this may result in unstable code, as future versions of `datashape` may change this variable without notice.